# How can I get the coordinates of some point on an already-settled Graph?

Tags: manim

In manim, I want to get the coordinates of a certain point on a graph?

````
class Formula2(GraphScene):
    CONFIG = {
        "x_min" : 0,
        "x_max" : 100.3,
        "x_tick_frequency": 10,
        "y_min" : 0,
        "y_max" : 100.3,
        "y_tick_frequency": 10,
        "graph_origin" : [-4,-3,0] ,
        "function_color" : RED ,
        "axes_color" : WHITE ,
        "x_labeled_nums" : range(10,100,10),
        "y_labeled_nums" : range(10,100,10)
    }
    def construct(self):
        self.setup_axes(animate=True)```
What's my next method or function?
````

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [`coords_to_point`](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/blob/master/manimlib/scene/graph_scene.py#L137), more details in my [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJZoEErP3ww)

Comment: Thank you for support, another question is that, how can I set the end of a line, please? I didn't find a method like set_start or set_end...

Comment: Use [`put_start_and_end_on`](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/blob/master/manimlib/mobject/geometry.py#L487)